# Error trying to fetch from PostgreSQL (Nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Tags: c#, postgresql, macos, asp.net-core, heroku

I am currently trying to make a CRUD operation with a postgreesql database hosted at Heroku with a MacBook PRO 2019.

But when I try to get all entities on the database, gives this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrL6E.png)

on this line of SQLMapper.cs

```
reader = ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(cmd, wasClosed, CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
```

And this is the Swagger error

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1083
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 725
   at Repository.Repository`1.All() in /Users/leoferrer/Documents/Dog-Kitty/dog-kitty-backend/DogNKitty/Repository/Repository.cs:line 92
   at Business.AnimalBusiness.GetAllAnimals() in /Users/leoferrer/Documents/Dog-Kitty/dog-kitty-backend/DogNKitty/Business/AnimalBusiness.cs:line 26
   at DogNKitty.Controllers.AnimalController.Get() in /Users/leoferrer/Documents/Dog-Kitty/dog-kitty-backend/DogNKitty/DogNKitty/Controllers/AnimalController.cs:line 32
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
Host: localhost:5001
Referer: https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

this is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "User Id=ajdrmyhilrvkcd;Database=denu3og6hclbt2;Host=c2-52-2-118-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com;port=5432;Password=****;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This is my program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DogNKitty
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o => o.AddServerHeader = false);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Startup.cs

```
using Utils;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace DogNKitty
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
            services.AddOptions();

            // Add our Config object so it can be injected
            services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "KittyNDoggy",
                        Version = "v1",
                        Description = "API de Serviços do KittyNDoggy",
                    });

            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();

            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            const string swagger = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint(swagger, $"KittyNDoggy");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

If more information is needed, please tell me.

Comment: It could help others to understand your problem better, if the complete error message were in your question, rather than just a part of it in your screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mapper is working fine? Maybe its a error tryng to map the object

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-language website. Please either translate this to English or try [pt.so].

Comment: No, it is not, because i tried to change the mapper.